# Sharing an Image

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-4.0

When I click the share button, it opens and shows some apps, but I click one app, for eg, WhatsApp it open and I choose the contact but when clicking the send button it shows "file can't be send". where I made a mistake, please help me to solve this code.

here I attached code for the share button.

```
//get an image from imageview
        Drawable drawable = imageView.getDrawable();
        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();

        //sharing image
        try {
            File file = new File(MainActivity.this.getExternalCacheDir(), "myImage.png");
            FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 80, fOut);
            fOut.flush();
            fOut.close();
            file.setReadable(true, false);

            //sharing intent
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file);
            intent.setType("image/png");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share via"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "File not Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
```

Comment: please accept my answer if it solved your problem :)

Comment: i tried  but it wont work for me... do u have some other idea to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
here is my android manifest file,

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.example.photoeditor">


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android-hardware.camera"
    android:required="false" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationID}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true"
        tools:replace="android:authorities">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_path"
            tools:replace="android:resource"/>
    </provider>

</application>
```